# J2ME Read ID3 Tags From Walkman (Sony Ericsson)

Tags: java, java-me, mp3, id3

Is there any way to read the currently playing song title/artist (id3 tags) in walkman on sony ericsson (w series) phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get information of currently playing song by the using of player MetaDataControl class. 
with the help of this u can find information like title,album,total time,content type etc....

Answer (score 1):

The Java ME API for playing MP3s doesn't tell you any metadata about the currently playing song. But if you know which file is playing, you can probably access the file directly, read out the first bit, and parse the ID3 info out of that. A quick Google search turns up several Java SE ID3 reading libraries. It's probably possible to do it in Java ME as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way your J2ME app could figure out what song is currently being played in the phone's native player application.